# what does "mata ha" stand for in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

くるまはみぎ、ひだりまたはまっすぐいってもいいです

i understand what mata normally means but, it doesn't seem to work in this sentence.

please & thank you.

Comment: Just in case, this は is pronounced as “wa,” not “ha.”

Comment: And what does it normally means? You might indeed be wrong about what it means…

Answer (score 4):

It means `or`. It is written as 又は.

Answer (score 3):

Since Teno has answered the main question. To supplement:

Looking at different parts of the sentence:

- みぎ、ひだりまたはまっすぐ - right, left or straight ahead
- 車は行く。 - the car goes
- 車は行ってもいいです。 - The car may go.
- 車はみぎ、ひだりまたはまっすぐ行ってもいいです。 - The car may go right or left or straight.

Comment: What did I parse wrong?

Comment: I think your translation is pretty much correct, but I don't think ~てもいい can be interpreted as "even if", I think it's more like "may" as in "cars may go right, left or straight ahead" giving permission. (I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer BTW)

Comment: Is that は pronounced "wa"?

Comment: @phoenixheart6 yes.

Comment: @cypher Thank you for verifying. I shall correct it. I included "even if" in parenthesis because I thought that it was a more literal one-to-one mapping. I thought the "even if" mechanism of も  leads to the "permission" sense of the phrase.